# Could not extract Info.plist from application: Plist file doesn't exist:

Tags: java, ios, macos, selenium-webdriver, appium

ON Mac Using Appium - Xcode - Selenium - java - downlord UI catlog app for practice 
appium error below

> Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Plist file doesn't exist: '/Users/mehul/Desktop/UICatalog.app/Info.plist'

```
public class base
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {


        DesiredCapabilities d = new DesiredCapabilities();
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6");
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.2");
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "//Users//mehul//Desktop//UICatalog.app");

        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),d);
}}
```

Comment: can you add appium server log? Were you trying it in real app or simulator? If you are trying to test app in real device, you may not have permission to install it in your device.

Answer (score 1):

ran into the same problem, restart appium server resolved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Following could be the cause of this error :

1. The `.app` is not actually a `.app` file but an `.ipa` instead.
2. make sure that the `//Users//mehul//Desktop//UICatalog.app` is a valid `directory`.